# My DC source (chrager) is 220 VDC, when measure + terminal to Ground, value is arond +110 VDC, Isn't it suppose to be +220VDC?

Tags: dc

as question above
when i measure + terminal to G = +110VDC
- terminal to G = -110VDC
Isn't it suppose to be
+ terminal to G = +220VDC
- terminal to G = 0VDC

Comment: Which charger? Why do you expect it to be ground referenced?

Comment: Could you post a picture of how are you measuring the voltage? Also post the charger you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It will only be +220V DC if the charger has its negative output connected to ground.

There is no reason why this has to be so.  Many DC power supplies are isolated, with no connection between the output terminals and any of the input power terminals.